# Как бот в дискорде может отправить сообщение после нажатой реакции

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    
    message_id = payload.message_id
    name_id = str(payload.user_id) #Кто поставил реакцию

    if message_id == himsg and name_id == player_id:#если вызванный на дуэль человек поставил реакцию то        
        channel = client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
        
        if payload.emoji.name == '✅':
            await client.channel.send_message(channel, 'Отлично, поехали!')
            
        elif payload.emoji.name == '❌':
            await client.channel.send_message(channel, 'Окей в следующий раз')
```

На это мне выдает ошибку о том что бот не имеет атрибут `channel`:

> AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'channel'

Comment: await channel.send('Окей, в следующий раз') - Я нашел это, и оно работает!